Accessing Python modules like scikit-learn from inside GRASS GIS’s Python Shell on Windows
How do I make scikit-learn from inside GRASS GIS on Windows?

You can install pip, scikit-learn, and other packages through the OSGeo4W installer as described on the OSGeo Discourse so they can be accessible inside GRASS GIS’s interactive shell.
